# Is there a "standard" approach to agile Perl development?

Tags: perl, agile

While not a "standard" -- this book [Foundations of Agile Python Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599810) lays out one person's view of tools and systems that enable an "agile" development process. Some of the suggestions in the book are not tied to Python (for example, SVN/Git/etc) -- but some are.

For example, aside from using `print` to debug Perl code, I've been trying out [Perl/Tk Debugger](http://ptkdb.sourceforge.net/) -- which is okay, and way, way better than nothing.

So, I've looked for books simaliar to the Python book, but focused on Perl, though I haven't found any. **Suggestion?**

Questions, feedback, requests -- just comment, thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're asking. Are you asking for a book recommendation, or a best practice, or what?

Comment: furthermore, asking if there is a standard approach to agile Perl development suggests that you think there is a standard approach to agile development; and I don't think there is.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [Extreme Perl book](http://www.extremeperl.org/bk/home). I realize that extreme and agile is not completely the same thing, but many techniques overlap.

Answer (score 3):

[Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) by chromatic

I've not finished it myself yet, but it might speak to what you're looking for.

As for your example, for a graphical interface to debugging, I've used ActiveState's commercial product, Komodo IDE, and I like the debugger it comes with. Also, [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/), a perl IDE written in perl, has some debugging tools that might be worth a look.

Comment: Currently working my way through chromatic's book Modern Perl; which by the way has a Download the Free PDF... :-) ...only thing so far about the book is I wish are the snippets were functional and had sample input/output; maybe via shorturls in the footnotes. Other than that, it covers a lot, and well written.

Answer (score 2):

Perl has a fairly extensive command-line debugger which is much better than just sprinkling "print" or "say" throughout the code and hoping that you remove it all later.  Check out http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebtut.html for starters.  The GUI tool looks fine, and is probably just a front-end to this stuff anyway, but you'll want to know the CLI in case you need to debug remotely over SSH, or if you want to show off.

Also, check out Perl Best Practices (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735), which is what many, many Perl-using teams use as a base to standardize their coding styles and approaches to problem solving.

Comment: Perl Best Practices is no longer consider the definitive word on Perl's best practices.  This is especially true about inside-out objects.  If you want to go beyond normal Perl objects, consider using Moose or Mouse.

Comment: @shawnhcorey I do use Moose when I need OOP in Perl.  I suppose I should have mentioned skipping over that bit.